# Sending mail with SMTP Auth on Linux, Cent OS

Tags: php, email

I have a script which sends quite a few emails to give notifications, however as it is not SMTP authenticated, the mail is going straight into junk. How do I make it so it is authenticated?

I'm using the following script:

```
$to  = $email . ', '; // note the comma

// subject
$subject = 'MineAlert - Server Down';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your server seems to be down, this could be because it has crashed or you have stopped it</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Your server seems to be down, this could be because it has crashed or you have stopped it</p>

  <p>IP: <b>'.$ip.'</b><br>
  <p>Port: <b>'.$port.'</b><br>
  <p>Reason: <b>Unknown</b><br>
  <br>
  This email has been generated and sent to you by 

</body>
</html>
';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: test@test.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if (!$mail){
    echo "Mail did not send";
} else {
    echo "Mail Sent";
}
```

Comment: Please be careful with the [`mail()` function](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.mail.protect).

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why the emails went to junk box may be various, e.g. you are claiming the emails are from some domains you actually don't possess (say gmail.com).

You are right that connecting to an "official" SMTP server (say, gmail) and send emails with that server will solve the problem. However, in my opinion, this problem shouldn't be solved/configured in php scripts but should in your MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) programs. A sample configuration with Exim4 as MTA in Debian can be found [here](http://wiki.debian.org/GmailAndExim4). Configuration in other OSes should be similar. It's not necessary to modify your php scripts.

[UPDATE] I did more search and found the problem can also be solved in php scripts. [This article](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm) may be useful.